# Vertical bars in Big O notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

My textbook has the following definition of Big O and similar for $\Theta$ and $\Omega$:

> $f$ is of order at most $g$, written $f(x)$ is $O(g(x))$, if, and only
> if, there exist a positive real number $B$ and a nonnegative real
> number $b$ such that $|f(x)| ≤ B|g(x)|$ for all real numbers $x > b$.

then in the text:

> If, for sufficiently large values of $x$, the values of $|f|$ are less
> than those of a multiple of $|g|$, then $f$ is of order at most $g$,
> or $f(x)$ is $O(g(x))$.

then there's the example:

> Use $\Theta$-notation to express the statement $10|x^6| ≤ |17x^6 −
> > 45x^3 + 2x + 8| ≤ 30|x^6|$ for all real numbers $x > 2$.

What do these vertical bars around functions and their expressions mean?

Comment: Absolute value.

Comment: @user10354138 why would one want to take the absolute value of $x^6$, it's always positive? The absolute value of a function (not its value) doesn't make sense either. I assumed the bars are used to separate the function definition from the factors forming function multiples (e.g. 10 and 30 in the example), but not sure.

Comment: The definition is more general and allows both positive and negative function values. The notation $|f|$ means the function whose value at $x$ is $|f(x)|$. This is a common way to apply any operator to $f$. Yes, in some cases like yours the abs value can be skipped but likely the example was expressed with the notation that conveniently matches the definition.